# Копирование файла настроек в шаблоне проекта Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

Делаю шаблон проекта VS и хочу, чтобы создаваемый проект содержал настройки и аргументы запуска внешней программы. Файл с настройками должен быть просто скопирован в каталог проекта.

Сами настройки VS хранит в файле `$projectname$.csproj.user` на который нет никаких ссылок из файла проекта (.csproj).

Тут возникает проблема: VS не копирует файлы, которые не задействованы в файле проекта. В `$projectname$.csproj` должно быть прописано что-то вроде такого `<None Include="$projectname$.csproj.user" />`, чтобы файл `$projectname$.csproj.user` был, все-таки, скопирован. Но тогда он появляется в `Solution Explorer` и настройки из него считываются только после переоткрытия решения.

**Project.vstemplate:**

```
<TemplateContent>
    <Project File="ProjectTemplate.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$projectname$.csproj.user">ProjectTemplate.csproj.user</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
</TemplateContent>
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно скрыть элемент в *Solution Explorer*, если указать значение метасвойства `Visible`:

```xml
<None Include="$projectname$.csproj.user" Visible="false" />
```

За старый формат проекта не отвечаю. Скорее всего, там надо указывать отдельным элементом:

```xml
<None Include="$projectname$.csproj.user">
  <Visible>false</Visible>
</None>
```

Это поможет избавиться от лишнего элемента в проекте, но вряд ли поможет с чтением настроек только после переоткрытия решения. Это попахивает ограничением IDE: разработчики, скорее всего, просто не рассчитывали, что пользовательские настройки будут создаваться не пользователем.

Кстати, если перейдёте на новый формат проекта, то там профили запуска лежат отдельным красивым файлом `launchSettings.json`, и профилей может быть много с разными настройками. Рекомендую.

Comment: Спасибо. Переделал на новый формат и настройки стали считываться сразу. В старом формате при указании `Visible = "false"` или `<InProject>false</InProject>` файл переставал копироваться в проект.